# Stop build if A value of type 'String' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'

Tags: wpf, xaml, error-handling, build

Some one had accidentally entered some random text in xaml like this:

```
<DockPanel>asd</DockPanel>
```

This shows the error:

Error   56  A value of type 'String' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

My problem is, is there anyway to stop the solution from Building? It seems to build fine, so it was later found by testing, but really it should never have built.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be easy. Simply open up the project in question, go to its properties, choose the 'Build' task, and you should see 'Treat all warnings as errors' as an option.

[image]

We have that off for our debug builds, but we have that on for our release builds.  That way developers aren't bugged about warnings, but they have to be addressed before we release.

Comment: Sorry actually doing that doesn't actually stop this from building. I guess it's because it's an error rather than a warning. If you have the file open, the designer kind of throws it as an error, but at build time it goes through fine, even with that set to all